# Pyspark: Find optimal k-value for Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis

I am trying to find a way in pyspark to evaluate how well my data is divided into clusters. This entails selecting a number of clusters k, where you will classify each observation into (in this case, probability of belonging in a given cluster)

In conventional python, I used the following silhouette score method to evalaute a k-medoids model. I am assuming there must be something similar available in pyspark. Does anyone know? Thanks!

```
range_n_clusters = [12,14,16,18,20,25,30]
score = {}

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
  
  clusterer = KMedoids(n_clusters = n_clusters, random_state=10)
  cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(test)
  
  silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(test, cluster_labels)
  score[n_clusters] = silhouette_avg
  
  print(f"Test k = {n_clusters} with result: {silhouette_avg}")
```

Comment: Double Like This Question